# Static 3D Array - Segmentation fault [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, 3d, segmentation-fault

I have to create static 3D array 200x200x200, but when I try to compile this code

```
int main()
{
    int arr[200][200][200];
    return 0;
}
```

program crashes. Debugger displays this error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

Does anyone have idea how to solve this?

Comment: The size is too big to put this array into the stack...

Comment: That isn't static, which is why it is put onto the stack.

Comment: Stack size is some MB. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481707/maximum-stack-size-for-c-c-program

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of space: 200*200*200*4(32 bit system int) are ~32MB. You cannot allocate that much space in the stack. [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27481831/1890362) and [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1825996/1890362)

Find another solution that involves computing less numbers, for example using temporal results to find other results, or saving values to file and loading them when needed

Comment: That's not 8GB.